# On morphism spaces of $(\infty,2)$-categories failing to be $\infty$-categories

Tags: homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory, simplicial-stuff, infinity-categories

As noted in [Tag 01WZ of Kerodon](https://kerodon.net/tag/01WZ), the morphism spaces of an $(\infty,2)$-category $C$ can fail to be $\infty$-categories, [in contrast to the *pinched* morphism spaces of $C$](https://kerodon.net/tag/01WY).

This feels very counterintuitive to me, as the only difference between the former and the latter is that morphism spaces have in a sense "two times as many homotopies" than the pinched morphism spaces: for instance, the 1-simplices of $Hom(A,B)$ look like this:

[image]

i.e., a divided square with two 2-simplices, one from $id_Y\circ f$ to $h$ and then one from $h$ to $g\circ id_X$.

Meanwhile, the $1$-simplices of $Hom^L(A,B)$ look like the right-top triangle in this square, with a 2-simplex from $id_Y\circ f$ to $h$, and similarly the $1$-simplices of $Hom^R(A,B)$ look like the left-bottom triangle in this square, now with a 2-simplex from $h$ to $g\circ id_X$.

**How should one think about this fact, intuitively?** Say, is there some illuminating example illustrating what goes wrong for morphism spaces compared to pinched morphism spaces?

**Second**, I'm also wondering about whether this problem might be "rectifiable" in the following sense: is there an appropriate notion of "weak equivalence" of $(\infty,2)$-categories making the following statement true?

> Given any $(\infty,2)$-category $C$, there exists an $(\infty,2)$-category $C'$ such that
>
> 1. The morphism spaces of $C'$ are $\infty$-categories;
> 2. The $(\infty,2)$-categories $C$ and $C'$ are weakly equivalent.

**Edit:** As noted in Tim Campion's excellent answer, the appropriate notion of morphism spaces for $(\infty,2)$-categories should be the right adjoint to the Gray tensor product. However, the morphism spaces defined by Lurie don't seem to be *too* far from the correct Hom, as they already encompass lax squares to some extent.

Answer (score 7):

It appears that Lurie has defined $Hom_C(X,Y) = Fun(\Delta^1, C) \times_{C^2} \{X,Y\}$ in Construction 4.6.1.1. This formula does not generally give the expected result even for *strict* 2-categories (unless $C$ is in fact a 1-category -- and Lurie remarks that this is the only case he expects the formula to be "correct"). In the strict case, it can be fixed by using the internal hom for the [Gray tensor product](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Gray+tensor+product) rather than the functor category. That is, the correct hom-category should be $[\Delta^1, C ]^{lax} \times_{C^2} \{X,Y\}$, where $[X, -]^{lax}: 2Cat \to 2Cat$ is right adjoint to the Gray tensor product $X \otimes^{lax} (-) : 2Cat \to 2Cat$.

In the weak case, the Gray tensor product can be approached in several ways, not all of which have been compared. This will give a general, model-independent formula for the hom-category from $X$ to $Y$. But the answer to your second question should be *no*: one does not expect Lurie's "Hom" to be "correct" even after replacing with some weakly equivalent $C'$.

However, the phenomenon of Lurie's "Hom" failing to even be an $\infty$-category is something model-dependent. I'm not sufficiently familiar with his model for $(\infty,2)$-categories to say much more about it.

Comment: Oh, the problem was the lax hom, thanks! I guess the problem then might be that Lurie's $Fun(\Delta^1,C)$ in the case of $(\infty,2)$-categories is supposed to be the "hom of _strictly unitary_ lax functors", as [remarked here](https://kerodon.net/tag/01YA), instead of those of general lax functors. (Indeed, the $1$-simplices in the morphism spaces Hom(A,B) look like [the square here](https://kerodon.net/tag/01L4), which is already a kind of "lax square" with the two $2$-simplices of $C$ there.)

Comment: One point that still bugs me though is that the pinched morphism spaces still manage to be $\infty$-categories while the non-pinched morphism spaces fail to be so, and the only difference between them is that the non-pinched morphism spaces have "two times as many homotopies"; e.g. the $1$-simplices of Hom(A,B) look like [a divided square with two $1$-simplices](https://kerodon.net/tag/00V0) and those of $Hom^L(A,B)$ (resp. $Hom^R(A,B)$) look like the right-top (resp. left-bottom) triangle in [this square](https://kerodon.net/tag/00V0)...

Comment: (I'll leave the question open for a little longer, just in case someone has something to add about the model-dependent aspects of this issue. Thanks again for your answer! =)

Comment: Er -- It's possible I've misunderstood the notation $Fun(-,-)$, then. $[A,B]^{lax}$ in my notation should have objects the (non-lax) 2-functors $A \to B$, 1-morphisms the lax natural transformations between these, and 2-morphisms the lax modifications between those.

Comment: Lurie's Fun(-,-) is just the Hom of simplicial sets, but I'm not really sure how exactly to think about its simplices in the case of $(\infty,2)$-categories... For instance, I'm not sure if they are supposed to be lax natural transformations or pseudo ones (I guess it would be lax ones since Lurie doesn't mention thin $2$-simplices), and the same goes for the higher simplices.

Comment: There's also some funny stuff going on with morphism spaces for Duskin nerves, too: [even in this very special case the morphism spaces can still fail to be $\infty$-categories, and having the hom-categories of the bicategory in question admit pushouts actually guarantees the morphism spaces to be $(\infty,\mathbf{2})$-categories](https://kerodon.net/tag/03L0)!

Comment: from that link it makes one wonder if the "balanced hom space" is trying to be some category of (co)spans